# Can't change color of GUI after upgrade to Lubuntu 14.04 i386

Tags: lubuntu, themes, gui

I push `Apply` but only changed color of `Customize Look and Feel`:

[image]

I close and start again `Customize Look and Feel` and see again white theme (I need dark for my eyes).

Comment: Have you tried to relogin? Or to restart?

Comment: Of course I tried reload my PC many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a new confirmed bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1316384

**[READ SOLUTION HERE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1316384/comments/4)**